# Propriedade do meu objeto está retornando undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonisjs

Possuo a seguinte função:

```
async geraQuiz(idEstudante) {
  let idioma = new Array()
  let livrosUnidadesGerarQuiz = new Array()
  const idsClassesEstudante = await this.getIdClassesEstudante(idEstudante) // Aqui obtenho como retorno o array [2,3]

  for(let i=0;i<idsClassesEstudante.length;i++){
   livrosUnidadesGerarQuiz = new Array() // Limpa o array para retirar objetos de iterações anteriores
   idioma.push(await this.getDadosClasseIdiomaEstudante(idsClassesEstudante[i]))
   livrosUnidadesGerarQuiz = await this.getLivrosUnidadesGerarQuiz(idsClassesEstudante[i], idBookClasseEstudante[0], qtdQuizGerar)
   idioma[i].quiz = livrosUnidadesGerarQuiz

   console.log(JSON.stringify(idioma))

   console.log(idioma[i].quiz[0])

   ...
```

No console.log `idioma`, eu tenho o seguinte array de objetos:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "ING-NOT-2019",
    "description": "Inglês Noturno 2019",
    "start_date": "2019-12-30T03:00:00.000Z",
    "end_date": "2019-12-31T03:00:00.000Z",
    "period": "Noturno",
    "language": "Inglês",
    "status": false,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-12-30 10:04:47",
    "updated_at": "2020-01-05 16:08:00",
    "language_substring": "US",
    "quiz": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "class_id": 2,
        "book_unit_id": 1,
        "book_id": 1,
        "start_date": "2020-01-03T03:00:00.000Z",
        "end_date": "2020-01-15T03:00:00.000Z",
        "book_unit_sequence": 1,
        "status": false,
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-12-27T11:11:21.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-30T17:54:12.000Z",
        "unit": 1,
        "sequence": 1,
        "description": "UNIT_01_GRAMMAR",
        "qt_question": 5,
        "miniature": null
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "class_id": 2,
        "book_unit_id": 2,
        "book_id": 1,
        "start_date": "2020-01-15T03:00:00.000Z",
        "end_date": "2020-01-31T03:00:00.000Z",
        "book_unit_sequence": 2,
        "status": false,
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-12-27T11:11:39.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-27T11:11:39.000Z",
        "unit": 1,
        "sequence": 2,
        "description": "UNIT_01_VOCABULARY",
        "qt_question": 5,
        "miniature": null
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "class_id": 2,
        "book_unit_id": 3,
        "book_id": 1,
        "start_date": "2020-01-31T03:00:00.000Z",
        "end_date": null,
        "book_unit_sequence": 1,
        "status": false,
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-12-27T11:11:46.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-27T11:11:46.000Z",
        "unit": 2,
        "sequence": 1,
        "description": "UNIT_02_GRAMMAR",
        "qt_question": 5,
        "miniature": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Porém quando eu tento acessar: `console.log(idioma[i].quiz[0])` eu recebo `undefined`, porém o meu console.log() mostra claramente que existe dentro de idioma uma propriedade quiz na posição 0, porém eu não consigo acessar pois ela está `undefined`. Porque isso está ocorrendo?

Coloquei um `return` logo após o `console.log(idioma[i].quiz[0])` para verificar se não está sobrescrevendo algo depois, porém obtenho o mesmo resultado; e

Coloquei um `console.log(i)` e obtenho `0` conforme esperado.

Comment: Experimenta trocar idioma[i].quiz[0] por idioma[0].quiz[i]

Comment: Undefined, conforme a pergunta, o i tem o valor 0

Comment: Pelo console.log do idioma que apresentou, há somente um objeto na posição zero do array e esse objeto contém uma lista de objetos no atributo quiz.

Comment: sim, e quando tento acessá-la recebo undefined

Comment: O problema é que a obtenção dessa lista é assíncrona

Comment: mas o await não aguarda a requisição finalizar pra continuar a execução do código?

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente é algum problema de inserção no objeto serializado que o adonis retorna da minha query, eu consegui resolver convertendo o meu array de idioma para um objeto javascript simples:

```
idioma.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await this.getDadosClasseIdiomaEstudante(idsClassesEstudante[i]))))
```